# Javscript Promises: How Combine .fetch() .then() and all()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch, chain

I am trying to combine `.fetch()`, `.then()`. and `.all()`. But I can't get it right. My case looks like this:

1. `fetch()` a record from an API. (My Item)
2. `then()` Search in this record for more API links. (Here I find the links to the media that belong to the item. Each item can have any number of media).
3. `all()` Execute an API call for each of these links with `.fetch()`
4. `then()` if all previous promises are fulfilled, execute the render
   function that depends on this data.

```js
// Prepare Request Header
this.url_params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let httpHeader = {};
    let request = new Request(api_itemURL + this.url_params.toString(), {
      method: "GET",
      headers: new Headers(httpHeader),
    });

// The first fetch I have wrapped a seperate class. I still need it from other places. 
    omekaAPI
      .getItemOnly(request)
      .then(
        function (result) {
          this.itemObject = result;
          let media_array = Array.from(result["o:media"], (x) => x["@id"]);

// Up to here it works wonderfully. I have list with all links. But after that it doesn't even jump into the all.
          console.log(media_array);
          return media_array;
        }.bind(this)
      )
      .all(
        media_array.map((media_array) =>
          fetch(url).then(function () {
            console.log("Its works!?!");
          })
        )
      );
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and could use a push in the right direction.

**Follow-Up Question**

Today I have now tried to process the input. Unfortunately, I cheered too early. I only got back the underfilled Promise. With which my loop of course does not work. I then tried to append `.then()`. Both inside `Promise.all()` and after the `.then()` in which I assumed it. Unfortunately this has the same result. I thought then should go back a step and read about Promises in general. Is it possible that I have to do this with `await`/`async`? But then I have to write the complete function differently or? Also, my babel/uglify completely freaks out when I have one of these commands inside. It would be great if someone could give me a hint if I can get anywhere with my code here?

```
getItemWithAllMedia(request) {
    return fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
      .then((result) => {
        let media_links = Array.from(result["o:media"], (x) => x["@id"]);
        return media_links;
      })
      .then((media_links) => {
        return Promise.all(media_links.map((url) => fetch(url)));
      })
      .then((media_response) => {
        /// debugging results from promise.all
        console.log(media_response); // (2) [Response, Response]
        console.log(media_reponse[0]); // ReferenceError: media_reponse is not defined
        console.log(media_reponse[0].json()); // ReferenceError: media_reponse is not defined

        /// desired function: all responses to json and push to an array
        media_response.forEach((element) => {
          media_data.push(element.json());
        });

        /// show created array for debugging
        console.log(media_data);
        return media_data;
      })
```

Comment: It would be better to show us what you have tried so we can pinpoint where the problem(s) is/are.

Comment: Okay, here is my code :-)

Comment: The syntax is `Promise.all(array_of_promises).then(array_of_results => { ... })` Rule of thumb: when in doubt, first check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Posting here should be a last resort

Comment: I did, of course. Not only specification but also some articles. But they don't combine these functions. Something I do not understand. That's why your thrown line doesn't help me either. But thank you for making me feel stupid with my first question on this platform.

Comment: Here is an example using your code. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/258fd69dc628f6dfddec678e4f98fea1 We all feel stupid sometimes, don't sweat it. The SO platform can be a bit harsh sometimes, but you should avoid feeling attacked. As long as your questions show effort on your part and are formulated decently well you'll probably fine.

Comment: ahhh! i have to do this with return. totally good! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: yes, I think I should have made it clear from the beginning that I've been tinkering for 2 hours^^ Thanks anyway for the welcome ;-)

Comment: It works wonderfully! If you ever delete the github link, here for the others, the solution to the problem:
.then((media_array) => {
        return Promise.all(media_array.map(url => fetch(url)));
 })

Comment: @HomerPitt You can even write it shorter if you use an [arrow function with implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) `.then(media_array => Promise.all(media_array.map(url => fetch(url))))`

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. Also thanks for improving my question. Nice system that you can do that.

Comment: i have added a following question, i don't know if this is common here. but i thought it is cleaner than starting a new one.